# Cancel multiple requests XMPP IOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, vcf-vcard

I am new to this XMPP and I am facing the problem in cancelling multiple requests in XMPP. The scenario is that I am hitting request for vCard fetch using `fetchvCardTempForJID` method. Since I have 1110 contacts in my contact book, it iterates 1110 times. now there is no way to cancel the requests that has been sent. now if the user opens "MY Contact" screen multiple times it will hit same 1110 requests and it keeps on adding. How to I cancel the previous requests that has been invoked? Is there a better way to fetch all the contacts or how do I cancel the requests?

Answer (score 0):

XMPPFramework do caching with `XMPPVCardCoreDataStorage`, and if `XMPPVCardAvatarModule` is enabled (and supported by your contacts or server) - can refresh vCards only when user notify you about updated avatar.